# SQL for quantity on hand at each location?

Tags: sql, sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012

Let's say I have an ITEMID and I want to know the quantity on hand at each location.  I've been told I need to use the INVENTITEMLOCATION table and the INVENTSUM table.  However, there appears to be no obvious way to join the tables to get what I need.  What table and/or keys link the two tables I mentioned?

```
    SELECT l.WMSPICKINGLOCATION
          ,s.PHYSICALINVENT
      FROM INVENTITEMLOCATION l
INNER JOIN ?????? i
        ON l.??? = i.???
INNER JOIN INVENTSUM s
        ON i.??? = s.???
     WHERE l.ITEMID = '#######'
```

Comment: ...I'm going to assume this schema is from [tag:axapta], otherwise this would be a futile exercise in psychic debugging (and would need to be closed).  For future questions, if you provide the table layouts (and potentially a good description of the columns/data therein, plus maybe sample data), you can get help from people who don't know the schema, but **do** understand SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join `InventDim` on `InventDimId`.

In X++, properly formatted, it looks like:

```
InventItemLocation InventItemLocation;
InventDim inventDim;
InventSum inventSum;
while select WMSPickingLocation from inventItemLocation
    join TableId from inventDim
    join PhysicalInvent from inventSum
    where inventSum.InventDimId == inventSum.InventDimId &&
          inventSum.ItemId == inventItemLocation.ItemId
{    
}
```

This works but will not give you what you claim: on hand at each location. This is like:

```
InventDim inventDim;
InventSum inventSum;
while select InventLocationId from inventDim
    group InventLocationId
    join sum(PhysicalInvent) from inventSum
    group ItemId
    where inventSum.InventDimId == inventSum.InventDimId
{    
}
```

When translating to SQL yourself remember to join on `DataAreaId` and `PartitionId` as well.

Comment: Thank you!  This is my first time working with Dynamics AX, and we've been dealing with a less than satisfactory consultant who has caused me to miss a deadline.